# Unchecked Cast: Map Output is firing unchecked cast warning

Tags: java, casting, warnings

I have the following line of code:

```
List<String> variandIds=(List<String>)parameters.get(AnalysisConstants.VARIANT_LOOKUPS_ID_LIST);
```

it fires the following warning: `Unchecked cast 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.List<java.lang.String>'`

`parameters` here is a map.

I need to get rid of the warning so I want to figure out a way to check the value of the list
now I could use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` but I don't want to I want to solve the problem rather than ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter variable declaration doesn't use generics or have key declared to be of type Object.

If parameters variable is something you have control over, you should change the declaration to use generics.

If it's not under your control, nothing you can do except suppressing the warning.

EDIT :

`private List<VariantLookup> updateSelectedVariants(Map parameters)`

should then be

`private List<VariantLookup> updateSelectedVariants(Map<KEY_TYPE,List<String>> parameters)`

Comment: I don't get what do you mean? what happen is that A List of Strings is wrapped as Object in a map along with other collections and is passed to another method. here I unwrap this object to it's initial state 'list of strings'.

Comment: What is the variable declaration for the `parameters` ?

Comment: the parameters is an argument of this method `private List<VariantLookup> updateSelectedVariants(Map parameters)`

Comment: Thanks for the edit, unfortunately I use other Lists of other types in the same method :( but I will try to optimize the design.

Comment: In that case how do you decide what kind of a list are you going to cast to? From the key? Well if that is the case you will have to suppress it or make sure only one type of List is in the Map...

Comment: yes from the key. I will continue to supress it till I enhance my design. Thanks